# Novice - How cut littles holes symmetrically on a cube

Tags: modifiers

novice here. I want to make 3D mattress, and I want to simulate the mattress cover like on this picture:

I want to add this little holes symmetrically around my cube. What is the easiest method to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a displacement map, maybe you could get away with using a normal map, depends a little on where you want to use that mattress (in a game or in an offline rendering)

or maybe, if you are crazy, you could even sculpt it, make yourself a brush tip in that shape.

Comment: its for product showcase, so to render it along with it's layers (I am making half mattress breakup). And is there any youtube video about it?

Comment: This one here is good: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_cbcV1_rgZg

Comment: thank You for helping me. I will try every step You told, and find which one suits me best. <3

Comment: one useful thing to know with micro displacement: if you change the multiply value in the shader, you have to restart the rendering. so if you are in interactive rendering mode, the height will only change if you go into e.g. solid mode and back to rendered mode again.

Comment: got it, thanks for the tip. Anyways, Im not sure if I will go with displacement as my first steps with blender. But I will try to learn step by step this, it has so great potential as I see